# MX record and Google Cloud platform

Tags: mx, google-cloud

I've recently started using the Google Cloud platform.

I registered a domain through name.com and setup a virtual machine on the google compute engine with a static IP. Then I created a cloud DNS server zone using the IP of the VM as the A record and then added the records for the CNAME and NS.

I can't add MX records.
Error:
Server Preferences / mail server
ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
Invalid value.

[image]

Comment: This question is more likely to get a good answer over at the WebApps StackExchange site. We'll see about getting enough votes to just move it over there.

Answer (score 3):

You want to enter the following; the priority needs to be before the server name:

```
@.xgtkids.com.  MX  300

5 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
5 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
10 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
10 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
1 aspmx.l.google.com.
```

Comment: For completeness, maybe also mention that a *lower* value assigns a higher priority.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but instead of using capital letters (`5 ALT1.APMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.`), I used lowercase (`5 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.`) and it worked perfectly after that.